# Server ethernet bridging, fail-safe

Tags: hardware, ethernet, bridge

Is there server hardware available with two ethernet ports, that can turn into a fail-safe bridge when offline?

My use example is a server that does filtering and traffic monitoring on an ethernet bridge interface, but can turn into a straight-through bridge if power is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.interfacemasters.com/products/32265.html) is a gigabit dual ethernet NIC with the ability to be programmatically assigned to fail-open or fail-closed on power loss. 

[image: Fail open or closed ethernet]